# Insert New-Line Character to format Python Script

Tags: python, regex

So this is a bit different, but bear with me. I have strings of python functions with no new line characters, but proper indentation. For example (totally made up):

```
def calc_value(a, b, c):    if a>b+c:        return a    else:        return b
```

I want to insert newline characters prior to each set of 4+ spaces so that when I show the code in an interface it displays as one might read a python script (instead of one long line that doesn't make any sense...). I could use

```
str.replace('    ', '\n    ')
```

but this would only replace the first indentation and if iterating over the string, cases with double indentations would be split into two lines.

Does anyone have any creative Regex or other option for formatting this?

Comment: What about [`((?:\t| {4})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/N9Ryyn/1). This also assumes tabs can possibly be used.

Comment: This looks to match everything I was looking for. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

Converting my original comment to an answer...

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/N9Ryyn/2)

```
((?:\t| {4})+)
```

Alternatively (and faster) you can use `(\t+| {4,})`, but at this point it's pretty much the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517651/3600709) as provided by [Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%E1%B5%A9) with the addition of the tab character.

Replacement: `\n\1`

#### Usage

The code below was auto-generated by regex101 in the link above. Direct link [here](https://regex101.com/r/N9Ryyn/2/codegen?language=python).

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"((?:\t| {4})+)"

test_str = "def calc_value(a, b, c):    if a>b+c:        return a    else: return    b"

subst = "\\n\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

---

### Explanation

- `((?:\t| {4})+)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:\t| {4})+` Match either of the following one or more times

    - `\t` Match a tab character
    - `{4}` Match a space character exactly 4 times

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
In [22]: print(repr(s))
'def calc_value(a, b, c):    if a>b+c:        return a    else:    return b'

In [23]: print(re.sub('( {4,})', r'\n\1', s))
def calc_value(a, b, c):
    if a>b+c:
        return a
    else:
    return b
```

Answer (score 0):

## whithout re

```
print("def calc_value(a, b, c):    if a>b+c:        return a    else:        return b".replace(" "*8,"\n\t\t").replace(" "*4,"\n\t")
```

> output:

```
def calc_value(a, b, c):
    if a>b+c:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```